# Systemui keyguard window cannot perceive resume activity switching

Tags: android, android-activity, keyguard

There is an Activity A, which set showWhenLocked = "true". when it resume on foreground, android system will set keyguard occluded, then A requestDismissKeyguard finish itself, systemui will show notification_shade window aka keyguard but occluded is still true. At this time, any activity cannot show on screen because their window layer is smaller then notification_shade window.
Normally, a showWhenLocked-Activity brought to foreground will set keyguard window occluded from false to true, so that systemui will make the window invisible. In my case, the occluded attribute is always true, and keyguard window will never be invisible when any other showWhenLocked-Acitivty resume.
I wonder a solution to show an activity now without unlock device. How do I make keyguard window perceive foreground activity changing?

I didnt find a way to solve this problem. Maybe android make it on purpose? I just think it's resonable to show an showWhenLock-Activity on top of screen when notification-shade-window is visible and there was an showWhenLock-Activity resume already.